# JSON to ClientObject - SharePoint CSOM

Tags: json, sharepoint, csom

I am trying to figure out how to convert JSON received from a SharePoint 2013 REST call into an actual SharePoint CSOM type.  I am using the `Netwonsoft.JSON` library in the following C# code:

```
var contentType = jsonObject["contentType"].ToObject<ContentType>();
```

The problem is that this then generates the following error:

```
"Value cannot be null. Parameter name: context"
```

I do have a `ClientContext` object that was created before this call, but I am not sure how to pass it in.   I see methods like "FromJson" on `ClientObject`s like the one I am trying to construct, but it seams you already have to have the object constructed before you can use that...which confuses me.

Looking for some crowd wisdom.

Comment: Could you explain why are you trying to do that? Why can't you simply use proper CSOM code to retrieve content types?

Comment: Good question.  There is a client side Angular app that does most things, but then needs to do something the user does not have access to do.  The Angular just posts the Json it has to a Web API endpoint which can use App context to do what it needs.  I figure since we already have Json for a valid object we could use it.